# Remove words from Evolution user dictionary

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, evolution, dictionary

I accidentally added a word to the user dictionary in Evolution 2.28 on Ubuntu 9.10. How can I edit the user dictionary to fix this?

Comment: This was a good question - it should have an easy answer, but it's not straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evolution uses a shared dictionary.  Open a terminal.  In your home directory, cd into `.config/enchant/`.  There's a bunch of files here, but a recently edited file corresponding to your language should be listed.  For me, it's `en_US.dic` - the US english dictionary.  Any words you have added will be listed here.  Edit the file by typing `nano en_US.dic` (or whatever your language is)

Remove or correct words as needed, one word per line.

Comment: Marvellous! I tried to track this down, but that eluded me. Do you have any references that describe the background & reasons behind `.config/enchant/`? Is that aspell, ispell, gnome-spell, something-else-spell?

Comment: enchant is a generic spell checking library that is compatible with the ispell and aspell engines.  Originally developed as part of AbiWord, it's now found in gnome-spell and gtkspell also.  See http://www.abisource.com/projects/enchant/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enchant_%28software%29